# O que é safe method e safe operation em ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recentemente me deparei com um alerta em *ruby* que dizia:

> Model has missing safe method 'method!'.

Ao dar uma procurada vi que se usa o *e-comercial* '**&**' durante essa chamada, também reparei que alguns exemplos é utilizado para substituir o **`.try(:method)`**, mas seu uso é apenas para fazer o tratamento de erros?

Por que usar? Quando usar? e como realmente funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O operador `&.`, também conhecido como *Safe Navegation Operator* (Operador de navegação segura), serve para evitar erros durante o acesso a atributos ou métodos em seu objeto.

Quando precisa acessar um objeto ou atributo dentro de um objeto, é preciso verificar se o valor existe para que não ocorra um erro fatal por tentar acessar um campo que não existe em uma classe **`Nil`**

```rb
# country -> state -> city -> code
def city_code
    return nil if country.nil? || country.state.nil? or country.state.city.nil?

    country.state.city.code
end
```

Para não precisar passar por todas essas condicionais surgiu o `.try` que antes de acessar o próximo atributo ele verifica se o atributo existe naquele objeto e retornando `nil` caso não exista e seu valor caso exista.

```rb
def city_code
    country.try(:state).try(:city).try(:code)
end
```

Para simplificar ainda mais entra o *Safe Navegation Operator*, ao inver de chamar um método para verificar a existência do atributo ou método ele já faz o acesso verificando o campo, simplificando sua sintaxe e facilitando a chamada.

```rb
def city_code
    country&.state&.city&.code
end
```

Claro que não se resume apenas para acessar atributos, também pode ser utilizado para acesso de `Hash` e `Array` usando o método `dig`.

```rb
params = {
    acount: {
        owner: {
            address: "User address"
        }
    }
}

# chamada utilizando .try ou .fetch
address = params[:account].try(:[], :owner).try(:[], :address)
address = params[:account].fetch(:owner) { {} }.fetch(:address)

# chamada utilizando .dig
address = params.dig(:account, :owner, :address)
```

O método `dig` irá retornar `nil` caso um dos campos (account, owner ou address) seja nulo.

**Fonte:**

> [**Mitrev The Operator in Ruby**](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)